# How to check if my vector contains anything other than x

Tags: c++, vector, find

I have a vector of strings allowed to contain only alphabets or dash(-) or both of them. I need to check if any character other than dash or alphabets is present in my vector.. how can I do this? my general idea is to use find from algorithm and tell it to find anything other than alphabet or dash...

```
if( find( vec.begin(), vec.end(), *what should I add here?* ) != vec.end() )
```

Comment: How about looping over the strings and using using [`std::none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with a predicate that check for `'-'` or [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)?

Comment: Even if you were to use `std::find`, you would want to use `std::find_if` instead.  Also, do you want to find *all* of the items that do not match your criteria, or only the first one?  Also, say if you did find one, what did you plan to do with that item, i.e. did you plan to erase that item?

Comment: Some programmer dude thank you seems a good idea. Will try to use these two functions.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie only the first one.. plan to cout "invalid" and not do anything else...

Comment: Use iterators and iterate through the vector until an element is != x

Comment: I think I would take the time to benchark std::string::find against a vector or simple array of char or const char* (a small data), initialized to identify the chars you want to handle special, using a simple for loop over each string.